# "I'm done" button disabled for reviewing late answers in IE8 compatibility mode

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, review, late-answers

When I review late answers right now, the only button still enabled is "I'm not sure".  In addition, the answers are all greyed out as if they had a -3 score or worse, as shown below:

[image: Late Answer image]

I can vote an answer up or down, upvote a comment, or edit the post, and the "I'm done" button never gets enabled.

I was reviewing late answers this morning without issue, so did I run out of "I'm done" votes, click "I'm not sure" one too many times, do something incorrect, or uncover a bug?

Comment: On SO? Works for me.

Comment: @YannisRizos - yes, on SO.  I just added a comment to a post as well, and the "I'm done" button is disabled.

Comment: Does it happens consistently, even if you reload that page? Sounds like something was not properly loaded.

Comment: It happened consistently, including reloading the page, as well closing and re-opening the browser.  However, I went to lunch and came back, and now it's working again :/  I'll leave this open for now in case it happens again or if anyone else experiences it.

Comment: For what it's worth, it just happened again, and closing and re-opening the browser (IE 8) fixed the problem this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to reproduce this using IE8 in IE7 mode.  IE8 seems to work properly.  We currently do not support IE7.

Comment: That's odd; as far as I'm aware, I haven't been browsing in IE7 mode at all.  Thanks for looking into this though.